# Selenium C # - Opening a FireFox browser through Selenium Different from doing it Manually

Tags: c#, selenium

I have noticed when opening a FireFox browser using Selenium I can log into into a website (using the line of code below). But when copying and pasting the exact url into a FireFox browser I am getting a certificate error. How can this be? Can any one shed any light please?

https://username:password@websitename.FIDS/

(Obviously I have removed the actualy username, password and website name to protect the innocent i.e. my companies details)

Also, when opening FireFox manually I get the SE IDE and FireBug Icons in the tool bar, but when opening FireFox using Selenium these icons do not appear. Really puzzling me.

Answer (score 0):

When Selenium starts Firefox it initiates itself with a raw firefox and an xpi to support Selenium stuff.  This will also disable firebug on startup as the add-on is tied to your profile and loaded with that.  This starts with a fresh firefox window for Selenium.  You can enable firebug with Selenium with some command parameters when passed in with the Firefox Driver instantiation.

You can also set it with a particular firefox profile instead of the basic firefox shell that is normally started with the driver.

Take a look here for adjusting the instantiated driver to what you want:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriverInternals